# How do I pluck user ids from all comments of an article?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I have an `article` that `hasMany` `comments`. A `comment` `belongsTo` a `user` and an `article`. So basically a comment has an article and user foreign key id.

I am trying to "pluck" / place all of the comment user ids, of the article, into an array.

I have a computed property that does:

```
userIds: Ember.computed('article.comments.length', {
  get() {
    return this.get(‘article.comments’).mapBy(‘user.id’);
  }
})
```

Returns: `[undefined]`.

Expected result: `[1,2,3,4]`. Assuming `1,2,3,4` are user ids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the incorrect dependent key for your computed property. That will only update when the length updates, not when any of the models resolve. You should be using `'article.comments.@each.user.id'`. Just remember that the computed property will re-compute several times and won't give the correct* value until the final computation.

* *theoretically* that should be all you need for the correct value. However, hasMany relationship promises have given me a **lot** of trouble in the past. I've had to do some nasty hacks to get around it. Hopefully changing the dependent key is all you need.

Comment: You are right. Except you can only go one level deep. So `article.comments.@each.user` works fine too. You might want to edit your answer. Since ember ignores anything deeper that one level